# PowerShell command to move to the root directory

Tags: powershell, command

Commands for changing the directory, using `cd`, are the same in PowerShell as in cmd.

However, the problem occurred when I wanted to move to the root directory.

If I'm on disk **C**, just write

```
cd C:\
```

However, in cmd it was possible to use a simpler command.

```
cd...
```

But, it is only possible in cmd. It does not work in PowerShell.

**cd... : The term 'cd...' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check t
he spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

Is there any alternative to this command in PowerShell, please?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `Set-Location C:\ `?

Comment: Yes, but in that case it's easier to write cd C:\

Comment: You could try to create your own Alias.. Create a function first `function CDC {set-location c:\}` and then create an alias `Set-Alias cd... CDC` .. If you want to use even after you closed your powershell you need to add to your profile

Comment: So there is no alternative for cd... in PowerShell?

Comment: From my experience No.. But I already doubt that `cd...` is a regular cmd Command.. I've never seen that before and it does not work on the computers that I work with at the moment...

Comment: Just adding to @DanStef comment (which should do what you are after). If you change the function suggested to `function CDC { Set-Location $PWD.Drive.Root }` it would work the same way even if the current drive letter is something other than C:\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what your after?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> cd\

PS C:\>
```

Or do you want to move from 'C:\Windows\system32>' to 'D:\' which would just be >D:

Comment: That's what I wanted. cd... seem more logical to me, but that is not essential. Thanks